# take picture crashed on real device

Tags: android, image, crash

I am using this code for take photos and in the emulator it is working correctly. It does not work on physical mobile devices and has an error on the Samsung Galaxy S4 and Sony Xperia Z2.

my code :

```
private void takePicture() {
    openCamera();
    camera.takePicture(new ShutterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
        }
    }, new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        }
    }, new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
            img_screenshot.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            closeCamera();
        }
    });
}

private void openCamera() {
    camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Size mSize = sizes.get(0);
    params.setPictureSize(mSize.width, mSize.height);
    camera.setParameters(params);
}

private void closeCamera() {
    camera.release();
}
```

Comment: post your `logcat` dump

Comment: i cant connect my device to eclipse , please test my code

Comment: Post the dump when you are able to connect it. We will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first be sure use permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

after that before call takePicture, call startPreview like :

```
private void takePicture() {
    openCamera();
    camera.startPreview();
    camera.takePicture(new ShutterCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
        }
    }, new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        }
    }, new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
            img_screenshot.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            closeCamera();
        }
    });
}

private void openCamera() {
    camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Size mSize = sizes.get(0);
    params.setPictureSize(mSize.width, mSize.height);
    camera.setParameters(params);
}

private void closeCamera() {
    camera.release();
}
```